# Type incompatible with itself in GCC 5 when using -Wwrite-strings

Tags: c, gcc

Consider:

```
char f(const char (*x)[4]);

void foo(void) {
    typeof(*"FOO") x[4];
    f(&x);
}
```

Compile with `-Wwrite-strings`:

```
gcc-5 -c gcc5.c  -Wwrite-strings
```

You get:

```
gcc5.c: In function ‘foo’:
gcc5.c:5:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘f’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     f(&x);
       ^
gcc5.c:1:6: note: expected ‘const char (*)[4]’ 
   but argument is of type ‘const char (*)[4]’
 char f(const char (*x)[4]);
      ^
```

Looks like a bug in gcc, unless I'm missing something?

Note: `-Wwrite-strings` changes the type of literal strings:

> When compiling C, give string constants the type "const char[length]"

Comment: In C, the type of `*"FOO"` is `char`. Is `-Wwrite-strings` supposed to change this (making the compiler nonstandard)? If it's not, the bug is displaying the type of `&x` as  `const char (*)[4]`: there is no `const`.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Consider filing a bug report.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Even so, a `char (*)[4]` is convertible to a `const char (*)[4]` correct? Why would it be an "incompatible pointer type"?

Comment: @R_Kapp you're right. In gcc 5 (and clang 3.7), turning off `-Wwrite-strings` compiles without warnings, but there is *another* bug in gcc 4 which doesn't convert properly the `char (*)[4]` to `const char (*)[4]`. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376481/gcc-incompatible-pointer-type-using-a-typedef)

Comment: @PascalCuoq, yes, `-Wwrite-strings` does exactly that. Updated the question.

Comment: @R_Kapp I would guess that `-Wwrite-string` is implemented by making `"FOO"` an array of some weird type that is printed as `const char` but isn't really and they didn't implement the conversions right for that weird type.

Comment: @R_Kapp Nope. Not convertible. A `const` qualifier may only be added through conversion after one indirection, so `char (*)[4]` can be assigned to `char(*const)[4]` but not `const chr(*)[4]`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Huh... did not know that. Is there a reason for this restriction?

Comment: Its a bug related to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57475

Comment: @R_Kapp If I recall correctly, any slightly more complex rule could violate `const` correctness and the WG14 thought that the very complex set of rules C++ has for implicit `const` are too complex for C.

Comment: @haccks I don't think this is related to the scope of types, no types are defined or declared by OP.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's indeed a bug in `gcc` `5`.

`gcc` [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says

> -Wwrite-strings
>
> When compiling C, give string constants the type const char[length] so that copying the address of one into a non-const char * pointer produces a warning.

So with this declaration:

```
typeof(*"FOO") x[4];
```

then `&x` is of type `const char (*)[4]` when `-Wwrite-strings` is present. In Standard C, `&x` is of type `char (*)[4]`.

This small function:

```
void foo(void) {
    typeof(*"FOO") x[4];
    printf("%d\n", __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(&x), const char (*)[4]));
    printf("%d\n", __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(&x), char (*)[4]));
}
```

prints:

```
1
0
```

with `gcc` `5.3` and `-Wwrite-strings`. So we can see that `gcc` `5.3` correctly identifies `&x` as of type `const char (*)[4]` with `-Wwrite-strings`.

`gcc` should then accept argument `&x` when calling a function that has a `const char (*)[4]` parameter. Warning for incompatible type is IMHO then a bug in `gcc`.

(This bug probably didn't show in previous versions of `gcc` simply because `gcc` failed (another bug) to identify `&x` as a `const char (*)[4]` with `-Wwrite-strings` in previous `gcc` versions. I tested with `gcc` `4.9.2` and `gcc-6-20151206`.)